# Storing dataframe differences when dataframes have similar column names

Tags: sql, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to verify count column from both data frames have an equal count column and if there is mismatch then it should store in a separate data frames for a specific data frames respectively either if the rows of first  data frame is not there or the count is not equal.

SQL Solution

Data Creation:

```sql
CREATE TABLE A (
  a_row VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
   counting INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO A 
    (a_row, counting) 
VALUES 
    ("abc|def|2022-05-27|09:05:17.023|12345",2),
    ("xyz|def|2022-05-27|09:05:17.023|13432",2),
    ("lkj|def|2022-05-07|09:05:17.023|14362",3);
    
CREATE TABLE B (
  b_row VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
   counting INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO B 
    (b_row, counting) 
VALUES 
    ("abc|def|2022-05-27|09:05:17.023|12345",2),
    ("xyz|def|2022-05-27|09:05:17.023|13432",1),
    ("poi|def|2022-05-27|09:50:17.023|450545",2);
```

Queries:

```sql
-- rows of A not repeated exactly similar in B
select a.a_row, a.counting from A as a
left outer join B as b 
on b.b_row = a.a_row
where b.counting  != a.counting or b.counting is Null;;

-- rows of B not repeated exactly similar in A
select b.b_row, b.counting
 from B as b
 left outer join A as a
 on a.a_row = b.b_row
 where b.counting  != a.counting or a.counting is Null;
```

Results:

```
        a_row                          counting
xyz|def|2022-05-27|09:05:17.023|13432     1
lkj|def|2022-05-07|09:05:17.023|14362     3

        b_row                           counting
xyz|def|2022-05-27|09:05:17.023|13432     2
poi|def|2022-05-27|09:50:17.023|450545    2
```

These are the answers I am looking to store it in a separate data frames.

Now creating data frames in PySpark

Data frame: A

```
+--------------------------------------------+-----+
|a_row                                       |count|
+--------------------------------------------+-----+
abc|def|2022-05-27|09:05:17.023|12345        | 2   |
xyz|def|2022-05-27|09:05:17.023|13432        | 2   |
lkj|def|2022-05-07|09:05:17.023|14362        | 3   |
+--------------------------------------------+-----+
```

Data frame: B

```
+--------------------------------------------+-----+
|b_row                                       |count|
+-------------------------------------- -----+-----+
abc|def|2022-05-27|09:05:17.023|12345        | 2   |
xyz|def|2022-05-27|09:05:17.023|13432        | 1   |
lkj|def|2022-05-07|09:05:17.023|14362        | 3   |
+--------------------------------------------+-----+
```

What I tried so far in python 3.7

```py
# finding the rows of A not found in B or count is not equal
A_difference = A.join(B, how='left', on='A.a_row = B.b_row').where('A.counting  != A.counting or B.counting is Null')

# finding the rows of B not found in A or count is not equal
B_difference = B.join(A, how='left', on='A.a_row = B.b_row').where('A.counting  != A.counting or B.counting is Null')
```

Error:

> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: USING column `A.a_row = B.b_row` cannot be resolved on the left side of the join. The left-side columns: [a_row, count]

I am not sure how to get the expected output which I got similar in the results from SQL queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing is that you referenced `A.col`, but Spark didn't know what is that `A`. You had to create `alias` for your dataframes first. Also, the `on` clause had wrong syntax.

```py
A_difference = (A.alias('A')
    .join(
        B.alias('B'),
        how='left',
        on=A.a_row == B.b_row)
    .where('B.counting != A.counting or B.counting is Null')
    .select('A.*')
)
B_difference = (B.alias('B')
    .join(
        A.alias('A'),
        how='left',
        on=A.a_row == B.b_row)
    .where('B.counting != A.counting or A.counting is Null')
    .select('B.*')
)
```